# How to set custom navigation controller back arrow image throughout app in the app delegate file?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I want to change all the back arrows in all navigation controllers throughout my app. I want to avoid changing the image manually in every file as that would be time-consuming. I'll post the code I have so far in my AppDelegate file in the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method.

```
let backButton = UIImage(named: "backbutton-thin")?.resizableImage(withCapInsets: UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 16, 16))
let backButtonImage = backButton?.stretchableImage(withLeftCapWidth: 5, topCapHeight: 0)
barButtonAppearance.setBackButtonBackgroundImage(backButtonImage, for: .normal, barMetrics: .default)

let item = UIBarButtonItem.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UINavigationController.self])
item.setBackButtonBackgroundVerticalPositionAdjustment(0, for: .default)
item.setBackButtonBackgroundImage(backButtonImage, for: .normal, barMetrics: .default)
```

The code produces this result in all my navigation bars ...

[image: weird backbutton arrow]

As you can see, the thin arrow is overlapping the "Back" text and the original arrow is still there. What am I doing wrong? How can I remove the original arrow and replace it with my thin custom arrow? I still want to keep the text though. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to modify the `backIndicatorImage` and `backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage` of the `UINavigationBar` class to replace the existing back indicator image with your custom one.

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().backIndicatorImage = UIImage(named: "backbutton-thin")
UINavigationBar.appearance().backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = UIImage(named: "backbutton-thin")
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you!

Comment: This does work, but then the vertical alignment is off.